# Bash: remove words from string containing numbers

Tags: bash, shell

In bash how to perform a string rename deleting all words that contains a number:

```
name_befor_proc="art-of-medusa-feefacc0-c75e-4846-9ccf-7463d5944061.jpg"
```

result:

```
name_after_proc="art-of-medusa.jpg"
```

Answer (score 1):

In sed, remove everything between `-` that contains a number.

```
sed 's/[^-]*[0-9][^-\.]*-\{0,1\}//g;s/-\././' test
art-of-medusa.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use gnu-awk for this:

```
s="art-of-medusa-feefacc0-c75e-4846-9ccf-7463d5944061.jpg"
name_after_proc=$(awk -v RS='[.-]' '!/[[:digit:]]/{printf r $1} {r=RT}' <<< "$s")

echo "$name_after_proc"
art-of-medusa.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is no generic solution, also you can use the following python script for your particular use case

```
name = "art-of-medusa-feefacc0-c75e-4846-9ccf-7463d5944061.jpg"
ext  = name.split(".")[1]
def contains_number(word):
    for i in "0123456789":
        if i in word:
            return False
    return True
final = '-'.join([word for word in name.split('-') if contains_number(word)])
if ext not in final:
    final += "."+ext

print final
```

output:

```
art-of-medusa.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not trivial!

```
awk -F"." -v sep="-" '
      {n=split($1,a,sep)
       for (i=1; i<=n; i++)
            {if (a[i] ~ /[0-9]/) delete a[i]}
       n=length(a)
       for (i in a)
            printf "%s%s", a[i], (++c<n?sep:"")
       printf "%s%s\n", FS, $2}'
```

Split the string (up to the dot) and loop through the pieces. If one contains a digit, remove it. Then, rejoin the array and print accordingly.

#### Test

```
$ awk -F"." -v sep="-" '{n=split($1,a,sep); for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {if (a[i] ~ /[0-9]/) delete a[i]}; n=length(a); for (i in a) printf "%s%s", a[i], (++c<n?sep:""); printf "%s%s\n", FS, $2}' <<< "art-of-medusa-feefacc0-c75e-4846-9ccf-7463d5944061.jpg"
art-of-medusa.jpg
```

Testing with `"art-of-medusa-feefacc0-c75e-4846-9ccf-7463d5944061-a-23-b.jpg"` to make sure other words are also matched:

```
$ awk -F"." -v sep="-" '{n=split($1,a,sep); for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {if (a[i] ~ /[0-9]/) delete a[i]}; n=length(a); for (i in a) printf "%s%s", a[i], (++c<n?sep:""); printf "%s%s\n", FS, $2}' <<< "art-of-medusa-feefacc0-c75e-4846-9ccf-7463d5944061-a-23-b.jpg"
art-of-medusa-a-b.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

Two possible solutions:

1. Using Sed:

   `sed 's/[a-zA-Z0-9]*[0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]*/ /g' filename`
2. Using grep:

   `grep -wo -E [a-zA-Z]+ foo | xargs filename`