# Counting distinct words in a text file: different results in Shell and Python

Tags: python, bash, shell

I'm running the 2 following scripts in Shell and in Python to count the number of unique words in a text file. However, the results are very different (123,832 in Python vs. 185,948 in Shell). Could you please help me explain what causes the difference and how to make the Shell command return the same result as Python?

The code in Python is as follow:

```
def count_vocab(text):

    # Normalize the text and get the vocabulary size
    tokens = list(set(text.lower().split()))

    # Remove all tokens that are not alphabetic
    words = [word for word in tokens if word.isalpha()]

    vocab_size = len(words)

    return vocab_size
```

I followed the answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/342164/use-command-line-to-print-number-of-unique-words) to run the command in Shell.

```
tr -cd "[:alpha:][:space:]-'" < <text_file> \
| tr ' [:upper:]' '\n[:lower:]' \
| tr -s '\n' \
| sed "s/^['-]*//;s/['-]$//" \
| sort \
| uniq -c \
| wc -l > <num_words.txt>
```

I also tried the 2 following ones but the results are nowhere near the Python result.

```
tr ' [:upper:]' '\n[:lower:]' < <text_file> \
| tr -s '\n' \
| tr -cd "[:alpha:]\n'" \
| sort \
| uniq -c \
| wc -l > <num_words.txt>
```

```
tr -cd "[:alpha:][:space:]\n'" < <text_file> \
| tr ' [:upper:]' '\n[:lower:]' \
| tr -s '\n' \
| sort \
| uniq -c \
| wc -l > <num_words.txt>
```

Thank you very much in advance for your help!

Comment: I don't have an answer, but you system to reject non alphas looks wonky. Have you tested it with that disabled in both of them?

Comment: @ValyrieH.Autumn Thanks for your comment! I want to count the number of distinct words so in the Python code I just took the tokens that are alphabetical. In the Shell command, I did what is suggested in the following answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/342164/use-command-line-to-print-number-of-unique-words

Comment: Alright. I'm going to load the scripts onto my system and go poke at them. I'll see what I can do.

Comment: @ValyrieH.Autumn Thank you so much! I really appreciate your help! I just added some more commands I tried in the question.

Comment: yeah so my guess was right, I'll go fix up the shell script, since I figure you want the behavior in the python script. (which rejects any words containing a non-letter, while the bash script will simply strip the number out and carry on)

Comment: Cool, answer is posted. Lemme know if it needs further clarification or smthn.

Comment: @ValyrieH.Autumn Thank you so much for your time and your help! I understood where the difference came from now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so, the problem in the shellscript (assuming you want the shellscript to behave like python does) is in the very first command you're supplying.

consider the input

> apple cherry bone0 cherry

the python function will, at the step that strips out words containing non-alphas, turn that into

> apple cherry cherry

while your shellscript will simply do

> apple cherry bone cherry

This is because of the first line of the shellscript, which simply knocks out numbers (from my quick test of it in isolation). Instead, you want the first line to be something like `grep -wo -E [a-zA-Z]+`, which will reject words that don't match that specific regex. (aka any words that contain anything other than letters)

also, credit where it's due, I got the patch from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50365542/11656314)

So, the fixed shellscript is (in nice function form)

```
function count_vocab() {
    grep -wo -E '[a-zA-Z]+' |
        tr ' [:upper:]' '\n[:lower:]' |
        tr -s '\n' |
        sed "s/^['-]*//;s/['-]$//" |
        sort |
        uniq -c |
        wc -l
}
```

invoked like (after you have defined the function)

```
count_vocab < INPUT_TEXT_FILE > COUNT_FILE
```

Comment: I just edited the answer mostly for style, but also to fix a bug caused by missing quotes on the grep pattern. See [SC2062](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2062) for details.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try and keep the formatting stuff in mind in future.

Comment: @ValyrieH.Autumn Thank you so much for your answer and explanation! I got where the difference in results between the 2 scripts come from now.

Comment: You're welcome :) I was afraid my explanation wouldn't make sense.